# javascript output random line from input

Tags: javascript, random, input, output, line

Is there a way to chose a random line from an input or textarea with a javascript?

Currently I find a few results that seems to be working, but mostly use jquery and other additional languages. I'm looking for Javascript only.
I've seen javascripts that pick a random line from a local file, I know how that works, but is there a way to do it without local file, and just from an input?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, split your input text by newline characters (that will produce an array of lines). Then take a random element from that array. To achieve this, use `Math.random()` function which produces a random float between 0 and 1 and then multiply it by lines array length to get a random float between 0 and `lines.length`. And finally, use `Math.floor()` to get an integer to be used as an index.

```
const lines = input.split('\n');
const randomLine = lines[Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length))];
```